# Switch off and on warnings in php

Tags: php, warnings

I have an script in `PHP` and i want prevent that just an specific part of the code show and logs `WARNINGS`. something like this.

```
    <?php
    .....................
    .........code........
    .....................
    switch_off_warnings()
    .........code........
     switch_on_warnings()
    .....................
    .........code........
    .....................
?>
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Why don't you correct the code instead of supressing helpful error messages?

Comment: Is an utf8 encode related error and is the amount of time to fix it doesn't worth it

Comment: I think this is highly opinionated. In my opinion, code that runs without warnings or notices is good, else not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You honestly should not be doing this, however in `PHP` you can suppress warnings using [@](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). You'd simply put that before any code you want to stop showing errors.

However you should keep the following in mind:

*Note: The @-operator works only on expressions. A simple rule of thumb is: if you can take the value of something, you can prepend the @ operator to it. For instance, you can prepend it to variables, function and include calls, constants, and so forth. You cannot prepend it to function or class definitions, or conditional structures such as if and foreach, and so forth.*

From the link above.

Comment: can i encapsulate the part of the code that will not show error in an function and use @ for the whole funcion ? will that prevent show warning in all the function ?

Comment: @eli.rodriguez you could write the function then call it, before you call it put the `@` before it.